# Error Running Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with Visual Studio Express 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Recently I installed Visual Studio 2013 Express Edition for Desktop. Before that I was running Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate Edition, which gave me no problem then. Now, after installation of 2013 edition, 2013 edition works quite well but whenever I tries to open 2012 edition, it says:

> Data Source Must be set by the time the window is shown

I am using ThinkPad x200 with Windows 8 Pro x64 bit.

Comment: Have you tried repairing Visual Studio?  That would be my next move

Comment: Yeah, I tried repairing VS 2012, but it didn't worked. So, I uninstalled both versions. Now, did a fresh install of VS 2012 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed older versions of Visual Studio. Installed only the newer version and kept it.